# Append string to each element of a list in Terraform

Tags: terraform

My idea is to have elements of a list modified by appending to each of them a string. How could this be achieved? I haven't find any function that allow me to do that.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Have you tried [formatlist()](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/interpolation.html#formatlist-format-args-)?

For example:

```
my_list_var = ["a", "b", "c"]
my_new_list = formatlist("%s-foo", var.mylist)
```

my_new_list will be:

```
["a-foo", "b-foo", "c-foo"]
```

Yo can also pass another list of the same length as parameter to append different strings to each element.