# Loop iam resources terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, loops, terraform, amazon-iam

I'm trying to create a loop inside the `resources` bloc on a `aws_iam_policy_document` statement.

I do have a local variable accounts_to_protect which is a list of AWS's account's ID

```
locals {
  accounts_to_protect = tolist(setsubtract(var.all_accounts, var.blocked_accounts))
}
```

Currently, I just use the first index of my list

```
    resources = [
"arn:aws:ec2::${local.accounts_to_protect.0}:*"
]
```

I don't know how I can iterate it inside the resources block. I tried to add a for but it seems to not work. I would like to have a resource arn per account id.

Comment: Use the technique in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51821961/append-string-to-each-element-of-a-list-in-terraform/51822639 to manage the entire `resources` list.

Comment: What are examples of var.all_accounts, var.blocked_accounts?

Comment: var.all_accounts is a list of AWS accounts ID, such as 111111111, 2222222, var.blocked_accounts is another list of accounts. And local.accounts_to_protect removes var.blocked_accounts if they appear in var.all_accounts and put everything in a new list of accounts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution is already in comments. The second one, would be:

```
    resources = [for account in local.accounts_to_protect: "arn:aws:ec2::${account}:*"]
```

Comment: It works perfectly thanks. Is it possible to make a single for with two variables?
Like this 
    resources = [for account, services in local.accounts_to_protect, var.all_services: "arn:aws:${services}::${account}:*"]

With var.all_services being a list of strings

Comment: @Michael003 Yes, it could be done, but details depend on the exact nature of `var.all_services`. I would suggest making new question for that with relevant examples and sample code.